# How to use auto-complete TextBox or a ComboBox in webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I am writing in VB using Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

I am trying to create an autocomplete TextBox or ComboBox in my web application that gets its source from a SqlDataSource. However, it seems like what I want is not possible (or at least not built in) in web forms. Also, ComboBoxes do not seem to be available at all. For the TextBox I have tried the method provided on MSDN:

```
Dim MyTextBox As New TextBox()
With MyTextBox
    .AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
    .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    .Location = New Point(20, 20)
    .Width = Me.ClientRectangle.Width - 40
    .Visible = True
End With
```

Full example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx

I have also tried importing System.Windows.Forms but that just gives this warning.

```
Namespace or type specified in the Imports '<qualifiedelementname>' 
doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found
```

However, the only property available to my textbox is AutoCompleteType, which seems to only work as a cache for user input on the web.

How do I use the AutoCompleteCustomSource and other AutoComplete properties of a TextBox in my web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent control for a ComboBox in ASP.Net is the [DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can use JQuery for autocomplete style functionality.  See this link: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox.

Comment: I am not yet familiar with JQuery and I am looking for a simpler solution like the windows forms AutoComplete. However, if I cannot find such a solution I will try this out.

Comment: I am marking this as an answer because I ended up using the jquery.